# Genre of Diablo 1's OST and music of a similar kind?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I love [Diablo 1's OST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcTAVQYMZv0) and would like to know the name of this genre. What other songs would you recommend? I've already listened to all the works of [Matt Uelmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Uelmen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, his music is "Classical Instrumental". It can also be categorized as "Classical Video game Soundtracks".  Overall, you would probably be best suited to checking out the Classical Genre.

Here are some recommendations to check out.

Personally I like Adagio for Strings and it has even been sampled for dance music.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izQsgE0L450

**Update**: based on your comment. What you are looking for is, Dark Ambient Classical music genre.

(2 Hours of Dark Music by Adrian von Ziegler)
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIrt5MkGpy0

> Mars by Gustav Holst, Night on Bald Mountain by Mussorgsky, Adagio for
>   Strings by Samuel Barber, and any of the four seasons by Vivaldi.  If
>   you want to try videogame music, try The Ballad of Sir Kibbles by
>   Suzemebachi, My Glourious [sic] Days or browse OCremix for remixes of
>   video games you like (try sonic).

Answer (score 2):

Acoustic Dark Folk like Nemuer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPQ6aXzi7CY

Answer (score 0):

Tehnoloogiline Paike - Kasvav Maa